# HTML5 Canvas translate, rotate, scale

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

for a little game i write a camera component for html5 canvas. You should be able to zoom (mousewheel), pan (left mouse) and rotate (right mouse). My Problem is after rotation if you try to move up the orientation is wrong and the image moves down.

I prepared a example here:

https://codepen.io/rogerbuecker/pen/yLzYqXq

My current draw code:

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
    
// Translate to the canvas centre before zooming - so you'll always zoom on what you're looking directly at
ctx.translate( window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2 )
ctx.rotate(cameraRotation*Math.PI / 180)
ctx.scale(cameraZoom, cameraZoom)
ctx.translate( -window.innerWidth / 2 + cameraOffset.x, -window.innerHeight / 2 + cameraOffset.y )
```

Regards Roger

Comment: What do you mean by orientation exactly? Also out of curiosity, does calling `ctx.save()` before the first translate and `ctx.restore()` after the last translate resolve the issue?

Comment: After i rotate the image 180 degree when i want to move the image up by drag and drop it then moves down. ctx.save and restore does not help here

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

https://codepen.io/rogerbuecker/pen/yLzYqXq

Missed the part where i invertSelf the Transformation to get the Position

```
var transform = ctx.getTransform();
const invMat = transform.invertSelf();
```

Comment: The panning works, but it is very glitchy. Rotate is out of control in Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have too much experience with canvas, but I have a little with css transform property.

Try to create a container object, inside it put whatever you have now. Then when you need to move the image or something related to have a persistant orientation just move or apply whatever you want to the big container, then to rotate do to the small one inside it.

Let me know if it works for you.